# IOS mail (horizantal scroll)

Tags: ios, html, email, html-email

I have an email that includes a long table and doesn't show well(gets jammed) in iOS mail because the width of the table is huge. I don't know how to enable horizontal scrolling for iOS mail application so the html emails will not wrap around.

Thanks 
Raz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a question of enabling horizontal scrolling. As long as your tables have defined widths you should be fine- the scroll bars will be there.

You could also define your viewport so zooming is disabled:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```

Maybe I'm not understanding your issue. Could you post a screengrab?

Comment: Seting widths to td did not help, iphone mail just squash whole table on its screen not allowing scrolling , causing signature to get on extreme height since of that.